# How to identify discrete states (oscillations) in Spark Dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sequence

[image]

A user U1 moves through the zones Z1, Z2, Z3 at time t1, t2, t3

[image]

A user U1 goes back and forth through the zones Z1, Z2 at t1, t2,t3, t4

This is what I call a user « OSCILLATING ».
[image]

This is considered as an oscillation: the user U1 goes from Z1 to Z2 and then to Z1. The user visits Z1 more than one Time eventhough he visited Z2 only once.

Z1 ==> Z2 ==> Z1

[image]

The user U1 goes from Z1 to Z3 then to Z2, Z3 and Z1, respectively at time t1,t2, t3,t4 t5.

The user is oscillation between the 3 zones.

As for the previous example, we consider this movement as an oscillation because the user visits and Z1 and Z3 more than one time eventhough he only visited Z2 only once.

For ease of computation we can set the number of zones max that a user oscillates in to 5 zones.

I would like to give to create a column that tracks the oscillation.

For a given user, if he is oscillating, give the rows the same oscillating ID.

If there is no oscillation, set it to NULL or set it to 0

For example :

[image]

Example DATA to copy/paste:

```
Zone, time, person, Oscillation_ID
A,    1,    ABC,         1
B,    2,    ABC,         1
A,    3,    ABC,         1
A,    4,    ABC,         1
B,    5,    ABC,         1
A,    6,    ABC,         1
C,    7,    ABC,         2
D,    8,    ABC,         2
E,    9,    ABC,         2
C,    10,    ABC,         2
E,    11,    ABC,         2
D,    12,    ABC,         2
C,    13,    ABC,         2
C,    14,    ABC,         2
D,    15,    ABC,         2
E,    16,    ABC,         2
C,    17,    ABC,         2
Z,    18,    ABC,         3
X,    19,    ABC,         4
Y,    20,    ABC,         5
```

Because I am working with billions of records I would need an efficient solution.

I am using Spark 2.3

I accept both scala and python (pyspark) solutions.

Comment: Have you considered adding a bounty, this is a complex question

Comment: Yes ! absolutely but I don't know how to do it ! I don't find the option create bounty

Comment: Ah strange, I can see it. This should be possible without udf's, I can see how but will have to do it when I get some downtime.  Can I check that 1) the example data above is your expected output and 2) whats the edge case you mentioned on the comment below

Comment: Thank you ! the edge case is that when you start with no oscillations and then finish the last rows with oscillations. it considers the rows before as an oscillations. I will to test it more as soon as I get some downtime

Comment: It will be great if you can handle it without UDFs ! The performance considerations is really important

Comment: Link of the proposed solution : https://github.com/heekof/Oscillations/blob/main/Oscillation%20Test.ipynb The line 6 and the line 4 should have the same oscillation ID. but they don't.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution using a window function with Pandas UDF to assign an oscillation id to each row after grouping by person.

I haven't limited max zones in an oscillation as that throws up a bunch of further business logic questions.

I have treated rows to be grouped in the same oscillation until proven otherwise i.e. last two rows in your example dataset are in the same oscillation.

Assuming the input data is ordered by time:

```
@pandas_udf(IntegerType())
def assign_oscillation(zones: pd.Series) -> int:
  current_oscillation_zones = []
  is_oscillation_frozen = False
  id = 1

  for zone in zones.tolist():
    if zone in current_oscillation_zones and not is_oscillation_frozen:
      is_oscillation_frozen = True
    elif zone not in current_oscillation_zones and is_oscillation_frozen:
      id += 1
      is_oscillation_frozen = False
      current_oscillation_zones = [zone]
    elif zone in current_oscillation_zones and is_oscillation_frozen:
      pass
    elif zone not in current_oscillation_zones and not is_oscillation_frozen:
      current_oscillation_zones.append(zone)
  return id

windowSpec = (Window.partitionBy(col('person'))
              .orderBy(col('time'))
              .rangeBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))


df.withColumn('Oscillation_ID', assign_oscillation('Zone').over(windowSpec)).show()
```

I have PySpark 3 and Python 3.8.

PandasUDF within a window function may not be supported in PySpark 2. Here's a less elegant solution using a generator within a PandasUDF with a groupBy that is PySpark 2.3 compatible:

```
def oscillation_generator(rows: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  current_oscillation = pd.DataFrame(data=None)
  current_oscillation_zones = []
  is_oscillation_frozen = False
  id = 1

  for _, row in rows.iterrows():
    if row['Zone'] in current_oscillation_zones[:-1] and not is_oscillation_frozen:
      is_oscillation_frozen = True
      row['Oscillation_ID'] = id
      current_oscillation = current_oscillation.append(row)
    elif row['Zone'] not in current_oscillation_zones and is_oscillation_frozen:
      yield current_oscillation
      id += 1
      is_oscillation_frozen = False
      row['Oscillation_ID'] = id
      current_oscillation = pd.DataFrame(data=[row])
      current_oscillation_zones = [row['Zone']]
    elif row['Zone'] in current_oscillation_zones and is_oscillation_frozen:
      row['Oscillation_ID'] = id
      current_oscillation = current_oscillation.append(row)
    elif row[
      'Zone'] not in current_oscillation_zones and not is_oscillation_frozen:
      current_oscillation_zones.append(row['Zone'])
      row['Oscillation_ID'] = id
      current_oscillation = current_oscillation.append(row)
  yield current_oscillation

@pandas_udf(StructType(
  [StructField('Zone', StringType()),
   StructField('time', IntegerType()),
   StructField('person', StringType()),
   StructField('Oscillation_ID', IntegerType())]), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def assign_oscillations(rows: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
  oscillations = oscillation_generator(rows)
  return pd.concat([oscillation for oscillation in oscillations])


df.groupBy(['person']).apply(assign_oscillations).show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but in Spark 2.3 there is no function "applyInPandas".
I think also that pandas version or an UDF might not be very scalable.

Comment: :( Oh dear. I'll look for equivalent.

Comment: @BendrissJaâfar I've updated with 2.3 syntax.

Comment: Thank you very much I will test it thoroughly tomorrow. But don't you think it is an expensive operation to go from spark to pandas and then back to spark ? (I have Billions or records)
Is it possible to write a pure Spark code ? or I should necessarily switch to spark 3.x

Comment: pandas_udf is in pyspark.sql.functions so it all stays in Spark. It will scale horzontally by person column. However, you will need enough memory per executor to process the data for the largest group of rows for a single person to avoid performance problems due to spilling to disk.

Comment: Thank you Chris, this seems to work, however I need to test it more. it seems to me that there is an edge case.

Comment: Did you get to test it and is there an edge case?

Comment: I will put the example on github and share the link with you. I don't know how to do it in the comments. But clearly it doesn't pass the test.

Comment: Here is the link : https://github.com/heekof/Oscillations/blob/main/Oscillation%20Test.ipynb

Comment: The line 6 and the line 4 should have the same oscillation ID. but they don't.

Comment: I've updated the criteria for freezing an oscillation set omit checking the most recent addition to the set. That way, the set does not become frozen if a person stays in a zone for multiple time slices. See if that works for you.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I will check it tomorrow. However, what I don't like about your solution is the for loop which makes the operation really expensive. I am thinking of creating a bounty hoping to get a solution without an UDF. Have a good day

Comment: It only loops over rows once for each person group through, so shouldn’t be too expensive.