# Assign an Identifier for repeating sequence of rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, cumsum

I have a dataframe where I need to generate the 'CycleID' column as below:

```
+-------+-------+----------+---------+
| type  | stage | Timestamp| CycleID |
+-------+-------+----------+---------+
| type1 | s1    | a        | 1       |
| type1 | s2    | b        | 1       |
| type1 | s2    | c        | 1       |
| type1 | s3    | d        | 1       |
| type1 | s1    | e        | 2       |
| type1 | s2    | f        | 2       |
| type1 | s3    | g        | 2       |
| type2 | s1    | a        | 1       |
| type2 | s2    | b        | 1       |
| type2 | s3    | c        | 1       |
+-------+-------+----------+---------+
```

**Data Constraints**

1. Each cycle for a type has say, 3 predetermined stages which occurs
   in order.
2. The individual stages within a cycle can repeat, but
   they cannot happen out of order.
   For eg, stage `s1` can never occur after stage `s2`.
3. The timestamp is guaranteed to increment between rows for each stage. Eg: `b > a`.

**The goal is to have a new column '`CycleID`' that uniquely identifies a cycle for each type.**

What I have tried so far:

```
w = Window.partitionBy("type").orderBy("Timestamp")
inputdf = inputdf.withColumn("stagenum", func.expr("substring(stage, 2)")).withColumn("stagenum", col("stagenum").cast(IntegerType()))
inputdf = inputdf.withColumn("temp", func.when((col("stagenum") - func.lag("stagenum", 1).over(w)).isNull() | \
                                                (col("stagenum") - func.lag("stagenum", 1).over(w) == func.lit(0)) |\
                                                (col("stagenum") - func.lag("stagenum", 1).over(w) == func.lit(1)), func.lit(1)).otherwise(func.lit(100)))
```

Beyond this I've tried different approaches with lag() but there doesn't seem to be a clean way to assign the CycleId.
 Looking for some help.

Comment: Here's a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66046331/how-to-identify-discrete-states-oscillations-in-spark-dataframe/66046980#66046980. Perhaps the answer helps. As per my answer to that question, I would go for a Window partitioning by 'type' column and then a custom window function to iterate over the rows for each type and apply your business logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data**

```
   l=[('type1' , 's1'    , 'a'        , 1),('type1','s2'    , 'b'        , 1  ),('type1' , 's1'    , 'a'        , 1),('type1','s2'    , 'b'        , 1  ), ('type1' , 's2'    , 'c'        , 1), ('type1' , 's3'    , 'd'        , 1),('type1' , 's1'    , 'e'        , 1),('type1','s2'    , 'f'        , 1  ), ('type1' , 's3'    , 'g'        , 1)]
df=spark.createDataFrame(l,['type'  , 'stage' , 'Timestamp', 'CycleID'])
df.show()
```

**Solution**

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.functions import *


df=(
 df.withColumn('CycleID',col('stage')=='s1')#Generate Booleans through Selection
 
 .withColumn('CycleID', F.sum(F.col('CycleID').cast('integer'))#Convert Boolean to intergers
             
             .over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0)))#rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0) along with sum function is used to create cumulative sum of the column 
)
df.show()


+-----+-----+---------+-------+
| type|stage|Timestamp|CycleID|
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
|type1|   s1|        a|      1|
|type1|   s2|        b|      1|
|type1|   s2|        c|      1|
|type1|   s3|        d|      1|
|type1|   s1|        e|      2|
|type1|   s2|        f|      2|
|type1|   s3|        g|      2|
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
```

Following your comments below:

Please sort descending and boolean select on `s3`. Code below

```
df.sort(col('Timestamp').desc()).withColumn('CycleID',(col('stage')=='s3')).withColumn('CycleID', F.sum(F.col('CycleID').cast('integer')).over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))).show()

+-----+-----+---------+-------+
| type|stage|Timestamp|CycleID|
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
|type1|   s3|        g|      1|
|type1|   s2|        f|      1|
|type1|   s1|        e|      1|
|type1|   s3|        d|      2|
|type1|   s2|        c|      2|
|type1|   s2|        b|      2|
|type1|   s2|        b|      2|
|type1|   s1|        a|      2|
|type1|   s1|        a|      2|
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
```

If you are likely to have multiple s3. Use lag as follows;

```
 m=Window.partitionBy()#.orderBy(F.desc('Timestamp'))
df1=df.select("*", lag("stage").over(m.orderBy(col("Timestamp"))).alias("CycleID1"))
df1.withColumn('CycleID',(((col('stage')=='s1')&(col('CycleID1').isNull()))|((col('stage')=='s1')&(col('CycleID1')=='s3')))).withColumn('CycleID', F.sum(F.col('CycleID').cast('integer')).over(m.rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))).drop('CycleID1').show()
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
| type|stage|Timestamp|CycleID|
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
|type1|   s1|        a|      1|
|type1|   s1|        a|      1|
|type1|   s2|        b|      1|
|type1|   s2|        b|      1|
|type1|   s2|        c|      1|
|type1|   s3|        d|      1|
|type1|   s1|        e|      2|
|type1|   s2|        f|      2|
|type1|   s3|        g|      2|
+-----+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: did this help you?

Comment: Thank you. It works for the given dataset but would fail if there is more than one 's1' in the same cycle.

Comment: What if you used s3. Meaning sort descending and proceed. Code here ; `df.sort(col('Timestamp').desc()).withColumn('CycleID',(col('stage')=='s3')).withColumn('CycleID', F.sum(F.col('CycleID').cast('integer')).over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy().rowsBetween(-sys.maxsize, 0))).show()`

Comment: Thank you. The only way to identify a new cycle is to see the first instance of s1.Otherwise all stages can repeat. I solved it by first using lag() to determine the first occurrence of s1 and then using your solution to do the cumulative sum.